# [How To] Prime Sense User Tracker Viewer

Tags: openni, openi-tracker, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
i am working with the Kinect, Now i fully installed openni_kinect.
I can Work now with openni_tracker and i also can visualize the published tf data on rviz but i dont now how to start Prime Sense User Tracker Viewer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10637/%5Bhow-to%5D-prime-sense-user-tracker-viewer/) by [bunower](https://answers.ros.org/users/479/bunower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By "Prime Sense User Tracker Viewer", do you mean the "NiUserTracker" sample in OpenNI or something else? Have you tried the commmand

> rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker

as specified on http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker ?

---

Originally posted by [Giovanni Saponaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/595/giovanni-saponaro/) with karma: 68 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-03**:
Have you figured out whether this package has the Prime Sense User Tracker Viewer?

**Comment by [Giovanni Saponaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/595/giovanni-saponaro/) on 2011-07-20**:
You're right, that package does not actually start the viewer (misleading documentation?). I suggest looking at http://www.ros.org/wiki/skeletal_tracker instead.

**Comment by [bunower](https://answers.ros.org/users/479/bunower/) on 2011-07-19**:
no no i mean only that video,  "rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker" but i cant see anything. I only want to se something like this: http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=nite.png

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2015-04-23**:
@bunower ,@Giovanni Saponaro,did you achieve this thing like [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=nite.png)?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think he means the same problem that I have:
We can initializate the user tracker without problems, but what we want is to be able to view the tracking with real time image, like the image of the http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker.

---

Originally posted by [xaescobar](https://answers.ros.org/users/926/xaescobar/) with karma: 11 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2015-04-24**:
@xaescobar ,did you achieve this thing?